# Socket functions in a separate file in Express server

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I simply want to implement my socket functions in a separate file (i.e not in the express server implementation) like (/routes/sockets.js). How can I do that?

My express server:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , socket = require('./routes/socket.js')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');
  ,app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

The socket listener (currently in the same file as above server implementation)

```
  sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
      socket.on('my other event', function (data) { //event on client
        console.log('my other event data ' + data);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out by my self. You can call the required sources using

```
io.sockets.on('connection', require('./routes/socket'));
```